# oracle 12c comandos para averiguar todo de los users

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Buenos dias a tod@s estoy empezando a trabajar con oracle 12c pero voy muy perdida porque me piden que muestre los usuarios que hay y sus privilegios  y roles y no encuentro por ningun lado ningun comando que me muestre eso me podeis ayudar. Muchas gracias amig@s.

Comment: Hola podrías hacerme saber si la respuesta dada te fue útil

Answer (score 0):

Para ver los usuarios debes hacer una consulta a la vista **CDB_USERS**:

```
select * from CDB_USERS;
```

Aquí obtienes todos los usuarios de la vista **CDB_USERS**.

Los privilegios se obtienen consultando las vistas **CDB_SYS_PRIVS** o **CDB_TAB_PRIVS**:

```
select *
from cdb_sys_privs    
order by PRIVILEGE;
```

Obtienes todos los privilegios ordenados precisamente por el **campo privilegio**, te aclaro que un usuario puede tener varios roles y un rol varios privilegios, en Oracle todo se guarda en tablas, ej: los usuarios del sistema, las tablas que creas, étc.

Para más información entra en:

http://oracleparatodos1.blogspot.com/2014/06/oracle-12c-usuarios-roles-y-privilegios.html

Comment: Aclarar que en 12c todavía era posible usar el modo de despliegue sin CDB/PDB, entonces depende...