# Como solucionar el error al crear un usuario en SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy iniciando un curso de SQL Developer, y me da un error al momento de crear un usuario, esta es la consulta de la practica:

```
CREATE USER USUARIO1 IDENTIFIED BY Kirflame1 ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Pero al momento de hacer ejecutar la sentencia, me arroja el siguiente error:

> Informe de error - ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol común no válido
> 65096. 00000 -  "invalid common user or role name"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
> that was not valid for common users or roles. In addition to the
> usual rules for user and role names, common user and role names
> must consist only of ASCII characters, and must contain the prefix
> specified in common_user_prefix parameter.
> *Action:   Specify a valid common user or role name.

Investigando un poco me salio una respuesta de que a lo mejor estaba conectado por CDB y que se tenia que cambiar por PDB. Alguien me pude explicar esto por favor.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416434/oracle-12c-comandos-para-averiguar-todo-de-los-users/416604#416604 entra aquí, puede servirte en un futuro y revisa el link que se pone en esa respuesta